# Can using the ruby flip-flop as a filter be made less kludgy?

Tags: ruby, regex, filter, flip-flop

In order to get part of text, I'm using a `true if` kludge in front of a flip-flop:

```
desired_portion_lines = text.each_line.find_all do |line|
  true if line =~ /start_regex/ .. line =~ /finish_regex/
end
desired_portion = desired_portion_lines.join
```

If I remove the `true if` bit, it complains

> bad value for range (ArgumentError)

Is it possible to make it less kludgy, or should I merely do

```
desired_portion_lines = ""
text.each_line do |line|
  desired_portion_lines << line if line =~ /start_regex/ .. line =~ /finish_regex/
end
```

Or is there a better approach that doesn't use enumeration?

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing it line by line, my preference is something like this

```
line =~ /finish_regex/ && p=0
line =~ /start_regex/ && p=1
puts line if p
```

if you have all in one string. I would use split

```
mystring.split(/finish_regex/).each do |item|
  if item[/start_regex/] 
     puts item.split(/start_regex/)[-1]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
desired_portion_lines = ""
text.each_line do |line|
  desired_portion_lines << line if line =~ /start_regex/ .. line =~ /finish_regex/
end
```

is perfectly acceptable. The `..` operator is very powerful, but not used by a lot of people, probably because they don't understand what it does. Possibly it looks weird or awkward to you because you're not used to using it, but it'll grow on you. It's very common in Perl when dealing with ranges of lines in text files, which is where I first encountered it, and eventually was using it a lot.

The only thing I'd do differently is add some parenthesis to visually separate the logical tests from each other, and from the rest of the line:

```
desired_portion_lines = ""
text.each_line do |line|
  desired_portion_lines << line if ( (line =~ /start_regex/) .. (line =~ /finish_regex/) )
end
```

Ruby (and Perl) coders seem to abhor using parenthesis, but I consider them useful for visually separating the logic tests. For me it's a readability and, by extension, a maintenance thing.

The only other thing I can think of that *might* help, would be to change `desired_portion_lines` to an array, and push your selected lines onto it. Currently, using `desired_portion_lines << line` appends to the string, mutating it each time. It might be faster pushing on the array then joining its elements afterward to build your string.

Back to the first example. I didn't test this but I think you can simplify it to:

```
desired_portion = text.each_line.find_all { |line| line =~ /start_regex/ .. line =~ /finish_regex/ }.join
```

The only downside to iterating over all lines in a file using the flip-flop, is that if the start-pattern can occur multiple times, you'll get each found block added to `desired_portion`.

Comment: Removing the `true if` part gives you "bad value for range".

Comment: That's probably an order-of-precedence thing. Wrapping each regex comparisons in parenthesis should clear it up, unless Ruby's parser is keying off the `if` to switch the meaning of `..` from a range operator to the `flip-flop`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save three characters by replacing `true if` with `!!()` (with the flip flop belonging in between the parentheses).